# How to parse type in rust macro

Tags: rust

I want to write macro, that convert this:

```rust
tag_def!("tagname", (isize, String))
```

Into this:

```rust
TagDefinition::new("tagname", ParamGroup(vec![
    TagParam::Int(0),
    TagParam::String(String::new())
]))
```

I tried to find some way to do that with macro but found nothing.
usual macro can't parse type, procedural requires struct to parse.
Is the non-over-complicated way exists?

TagParam is a enum:

```rust
pub enum TagParam {
    Int(isize),
    String(String),
    Color(Color),
    Tag(Tag),
    Float(f64),
    ParamGroup(Vec<TagParam>)
}
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean by "parse type" nor how the input relates to the output.

Comment: second arg of macro is type, that represents content of tag defenition. In this case, 
(x, y) => TagParam::ParamGroup(vec![x, y])
isize => TagParam::Int(0),
String => TagParam::String(String::new()),

Comment: by "parse type" i mean convert rust actual types to one of the enum values to pass it to parser. @cdhowie

Comment: What do you mean by "procedural requires struct to parse"?

Answer (score 1):

One way you can make this simpler is if all of the values stored in the enum implement `Default`, the macro can provide `Default::default()` as the value.  My suggestion would be to take this approach.  (All of the enum payloads in your example implement `Default`, with the possible exception of `Tag` and `Color` -- I don't know what those types are, but they might implement `Default`.)

Then, you just need a way to map an identifier (the type name) to an enum variant name, which we can do with another macro:

```
macro_rules! tag_def_type_variant {
    ( isize ) => { TagParam::Int };
    ( f64 ) => { TagParam::Float };
    // Everything else passes through as-is.
    ( $e:ident ) => { TagParam::$e };
}
```

Now we can build `tag_def` in terms of this macro:

```
macro_rules! tag_def {
    ( $name:literal , ( $( $ty:ident ),+ ) ) => {
        TagDefinition::new($name, TagParam::ParamGroup(vec![
            $(tag_def_type_variant!($ty)(Default::default())),+
        ]))
    }
}
```

Comment: `Vec<TagParam>` is not `ident`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Yeah, wrote this answer right before falling asleep and didn't test that case. Oops. I've been trying to make this work with macro_rules and I'm not sure it can, at least not this way. I think it might be better to have the macro accept variant names instead (e.g. `Int` instead of `isize`) as that makes the whole thing way simpler.

Comment: Yeah, I'm afraid it required tt munching.